# Qt - connect menuBar and QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

So I have menu bar like this:

```
this->layout = new QGridLayout;
QMenuBar* menuBar = new QMenuBar();
QMenu *fileMenu = new QMenu("File");
menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);
fileMenu->addAction("Exit");
this->layout->setMenuBar(menuBar);
```

And I am wonderig how to connect thie action `"Exit"` with some slot my `QWidget`, I tryed something like this:

```
connect(menuBar,SIGNAL(menuBar->actions),this,SLOT(exitGame()));
```

But it is not working, can you tell me what I am doing wrong? And yes I have read manual about QMenuBar bud there are no examples of connecting. I have read about some connecting in Qt Designer but I am not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the `QAction` pointer returned from `QMenuBar::addAction` to the slot...

```
auto *exit_action = fileMenu->addAction("Exit");
connect(exit_action, &QAction::triggered,
        [this](bool checked)
        {
          exitGame();
        });
```